# How should I setup the structure of my MySQL database to work for my needs?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am working on an application that awards the top person of each category for being first. The way you become first in a category is by having the most number of votes in the past 30 (or so) days. So even if you had a total of 2,000 votes but got only 2 votes within the past 30 days, someone with 10 votes but got all 10 within the past 30 days would be ranked above you. I am just trying to seek advise on the best way to create this type of system with a MySQL database and how to structure the database.

I am pretty unsure of the best way to go about this, any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This problem's solution is very dependent on your table structure. If you need help actually creating your table structure then you'll have to ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first desicion you have to make is, whether you want to keep a record for every vote cast: This has the potential for a huge table, but it lets you keep a lot of information, so you trade storage and performance against information. This must be answered by business logic, not implementation.

Assuming you DO want to keep every vote, keep it with a timestamp and the only thing you have to do is to join the user person table with the vote table, use a `WHERE` clause to select only the last N days and a `COUNT()` aggregate to count your votes.

If you do NOT want to keep every vote, you should have an accumulation table with person, day and votecount - an analogous query with `SUM()` instead of `COUNT()` will do what you want.

Comment: Would I have to like run a script every day with cron or something to calculate the result and send a notification to a user if they have become #1? This just seems like a very cumbersome method. I was thinking of using a method similar to how reddit does it by using the unix timestamp divided by 60*60*24*14 (two weeks in seconds) then adding that to the natural log of the number of votes on it. It does not give the same effect but it would be easier to sort and view and notify people when their rank changes to number one.

Comment: I was not thinking of a cron job! Whether you use a UNIX timestamp or some date format is just a matter of taste and again business logic: What about DST changes - is it OK to have 24x7 hours, even if that is not exactly 7 days? Running something in a cron job every day could speed up performance: If you have calcualted days 1-n already, you just need the newest in-line.

Comment: I would just need to run a cron job every day to check if the new leader has changed because of votes that have past 30 days so I can send I push notification to the new leader. I might also just have the votes grouped by every 5 days instead of every day, but that is just preference. Do you think that query to load the items in order of votes from the past 30 days using a JOIN would be a fast script?

Comment: Depending on your needs and the amount of data. You could allways cache the ranking in some throwaway table or field, to speed things up.